# biblatex strange formatting and out of the blue boldness

Tags: biblatex

[image]

When translating a document on windows it works as intended. But with my mac and biber it produces this. Do you know why and how to fix this?

```
%\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,english,reqno,a4paper]{article}
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
fontsize=12pt,
BCOR10mm, % binding offset
DIV=14, % how much margin
parskip, 
headsepline,
final]{scrbook}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=12,maxcitenames=10,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\bibliography{thesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}     % ams stuff should be before font loading
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % should be after font loading
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bbm}


\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\usepackage{longtable}

% math symbol related
\usepackage{amssymb, amstext}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
% Automatic brackets and context-dependent presentation
\usepackage{scalerel, stackengine}

% general typography
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility}, babel]{microtype}



\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{binary-units=true}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}


% layout
%\usepackage[twoside, bindingoffset=8mm, left=20mm, right=40mm, top=28mm, bottom=120mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[twoside, bindingoffset=8mm, left=20mm, right=40mm, top=28mm, bottom=57mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{changepage}

% figures and tables
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, % For easy node-relative placements
    automata, 
    decorations.markings, 
    shapes.geometric, 
    arrows.meta, patterns}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\newcommand*\Let[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2}
\newcommand*\Lett[4]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2, #3 $\gets$ #4}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}
\usepackage{setspace}



\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{booktabs}


\definecolor{lightmauve}{rgb}{0.86, 0.82, 1.0}
\usepackage{numprint}
\npthousandsep{\,}

\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

%\usepackage{typearea}           % custom type area
%   \areaset[0mm]{135mm}{210mm}  % typearea configuration
%   \topmargin5mm                % typearea configuration
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand{\bibhighlight}[1]{\begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.85\textwidth}\cite{#1} \fullcite{#1}.\end{minipage}
    \end{center}
}
%
%

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % wie tief soll das Inhaltsverzeichnis auflösen
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % wie tief soll gezählt werden


%% Blattlayout
%\textwidth15cm
%\textheight22cm
%\topmargin0cm
%\oddsidemargin0.5cm
%\evensidemargin0.5cm

% Einzug f"ur den Absatz
\parindent0em
\parskip0.5em


% Per SIAM Style Manual, "section" should be lowercase
%\crefname{section}{section}{sections}
%\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}
%\Crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}
%\Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}

% Per SIAM Style Manual, "Figure" should be spelled out in references
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
\crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}

% Per SIAM Style Manual, don't say equation in front on an equation.
\crefformat{equation}{\textup{#2(#1)#3}}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{\textup{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{\textup{#2(#1)#3}}{  \textup{ and } \textup{#2(#1)#3}}
{, \textup{#2(#1)#3}}{, \textup{ and } \textup{#2(#1)#3}}
\crefrangemultiformat{equation}{\textup{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}}%
{ \textup{ and } \textup{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}}{, \textup{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}}{,  \textup{ and }  \textup{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}}

% But spell it out at the beginning of a sentence.
\Crefformat{equation}{#2Equation~\textup{(#1)}#3}
\Crefrangeformat{equation}{Equations~\textup{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}}
\Crefmultiformat{equation}{Equations~\textup{#2(#1)#3}}{  \textup{ and } \textup{#2(#1)#3}}
{, \textup{#2(#1)#3}}{, and \textup{#2(#1)#3}}
\Crefrangemultiformat{equation}{Equations~\textup{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}}%
{ and \textup{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}}{, \textup{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}}{, \textup{ and } \textup{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}}

% Make number non-italic in any environment.
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\textup{#1}#3}


%\input{latex_packages/Macros}


\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Alph}

\cite{SyedSchapire2007}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\clearpage
%\listoffigures
%\listoftables
\end{document}
```

and the bib file

```
@comment{ -*- bibtex-dialect: biblatex; -*-}

@InProceedings{SyedSchapire2007,
    author = {Umar Syed and Robert E. Schapire},
    title = {A Game-Theoretic Approach to Apprenticeship Learning},
    booktitle = {Conference on Neural Information Processing System (NIPS)},
    OPTcrossref = {•},
    OPTkey = {•},
    OPTpages = {•},
    year = {2007},
    OPTeditor = {•},
    OPTvolume = {•},
    OPTnumber = {•},
    OPTseries = {•},
    OPTaddress = {•},
    OPTmonth = {•},
    OPTorganization = {•},
    OPTpublisher = {•},
    OPTnote = {Available at: \url{https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3293-a-game-theoretic-approach-to-apprenticeship-learning}},
    OPTannote = {•}
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Otherwise we have no idea what you are doing. Are you sure this is not some PDF viewer artifact? Is it still boldish if you zoom in?

Comment: yes and also the spacing near the "in" is off.

Comment: As mentioned we need an example. This might also be from compilation errors being ignored.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. You've shown us output but no code to show what you're actually doing. Without showing some reproducible code we're left to guess everything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this happens if you use a language for which biblatex doesn't provide translations.

Comment: I added the mwe and the problem is that the boldness needs to go away and the formatting needs to be back to looking clean.

Comment: Two `\documentclass`es looks like a recipe for disaster. You can only have one `\documentclass`. If you do decide on one keep in mind that `\usepackage{babel}` needs to know the language of your document, so you need to keep the global `ngerman` around (assuming you are writing in German).

Comment: I write some text in German and some in English. Yes sorry the first document class was commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following minimal example reproduces the issue you are seeing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  maxbibnames=12, maxcitenames=10,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. ?Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments? inJournal of Computational Chemistry: 19.4 (1998), pages 377–395. doi: 10.1002/ (SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P." with "and", "in" and "pages" highlighted in bold]

If you load `babel` but fail to tell it about your document language(s), `biblatex` will fall back to printing the strings in bold to warn you that your language setup is deficient. You also get warnings

> ```
> Package csquotes Warning: No style for language 'nil'.
> (csquotes)                Using fallback style on input line 14.
>
> Package biblatex Warning: Language 'nil' not supported.
> (biblatex)                Using dummy definitions on input line 14.
> ```

The solution is to pass the appropriate language options to `babel`. For a German document (as one of your two `\documentclass` lines suggests) you'd go for `ngerman`

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  maxbibnames=12, maxcitenames=10,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Literatur [1] Emma Sigfridsson und Ulf Ryde. „Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments“. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: that is black magic woodo, but it works thanks!! strangely on windows it was no problem.

Comment: @biberdoesntwork101 Presumably your Windows installation is older. In old versions `biblatex` would fall back to English, but this could cause issues if people weren't aware of that, so current versions really need a language declaration if you load `babel`/`polyglossia`.